# Why Chrome Date .toLocaleString() seems not to use windows.navigator.language?

Tags: javascript, locale

According to the documentation {Date object}.[toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) should use the browser default locale (when not specified).
The default locale is visible with [*navigator.language*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/language).

When my locale is "en-GB" I expect the output format to be DD/MM/YYY.
It is returning MM/DD/YYYY ("en" or "en-US") instead.
If I specify the locale to be "en-GB" the output is as expected.

**Why the navigator.locale is not used for the .toLocaleString() ?**

Date: 24 November 2021.

```js
window.navigator.language  // default "locale" ?
new Date().toString()
new Date().toLocaleDateString()  // is not using the window.navigator.language
new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-GB")  // ok, this use the right format
```

[image]

Comment: There are some open issues (from 2020 and 2021) for this topic: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=tolocaledatestring+type%3Abug

Comment: There are always some bugs in the applications, this one must be drowned in the long list of little things missed and must have a very low priority. There are also different contributors and you can contribute too  https://www.chromium.org/Home

Comment: Is there perhaps a deeper issue here, e.g., with the ES5/6 etc. specification? I am seeing the same issue in both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

As [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas) pointed out in a comment,
*.toLocaleDateString()* seems to have [some bugs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=tolocaledatestring+type%3Abug).

This **workaround** seems to work:

```js
new Date().toLocaleDateString(window.navigator.language)
```

Comment: Is there a workaround for `<input type="date">` or is this element exclusively for use by Americans?

Comment: If you use us english language but 24hr format, you will see am/pm for the solution above but `<input/>` will show 24 hour selection. Chrome still has this strange issue...